# View code attached to html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, button

I'm trying to view the code that is executed when the *Expand All Topics/Collapse All Topics* button at the top left of [this page](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/2day_dba/12cr1db_ch2install/12cr1db_ch2install.html#overview) is toggled.  I've looked at the source and dug around in the Chrome Inspector, but I haven't managed to find it. It doesn't list any listeners. The source is pretty simple, so I think it should be straightforward. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: js/basic.js line #321.

Comment: When you want to see what code is running on any user action (such as click, drag), you can go to `Source` tab in Chrome Dev Tools, on left side you have `Event Listener Breakpoints`, there you can put breakpoint on click event and it will take you to the Target code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. When I set the breakpoint, execution stops inside the jquery source itself (#1264), not inside basic.js. If I step out of the jquery script, it takes me back to #378 of basic.js. How did you arrive at #321?

Answer (score 1):

The id of the button is `tglTopicBtn`

The code is:

```
$("#tglTopicBtn").button({
    icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-s"}
}).click(function() {
    lastClickedSection = undefined;
    var options;
    if ($(this).text() === "Expand All Topics") {
        options = {
            label: "Collapse All Topics",
            icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-n"}
        };
        showSections();
    }
    else {
        options = {
            label: "Expand All Topics",
            icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-s"}
        };
        hideSections();
    }
    $(this).button("option", options);
    updateSelectedSection();
    return false;
});
```

I found it under `F12/source/js/basic.js`

Here are the steps to find source code when accessed with jQuery, for the future:

- If you are looking for the js code associated to a `div` in a web, select `View page source` within right-click options.
- If there is some text within that div, find it with `crtl+f`. In this case I found `<button id="tglTopicBtn">Expand All Topics</button>`
- Go to `F12/Source`, and look for JScript code. Look for the id (`tglTopicBtn` here) with `ctrl+f` in files with plausible names. Files like `bootstrap.js` or `jquery.js` are usually downloaded. In this case, `basic.js` and `hooks.js` looked like specific code for the site.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in basic.js:

line #321

```
$("#tglTopicBtn").button({
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-s"}
    }).click(function() {
        lastClickedSection = undefined;
        var options;
        if ($(this).text() === "Expand All Topics") {
            options = {
                label: "Collapse All Topics",
                icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-n"}
            };
            showSections();
        }
        else {
            options = {
                label: "Expand All Topics",
                icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-s"}
            };
            hideSections();
        }
        $(this).button("option", options);
        updateSelectedSection();
        return false;
    });
```

line #191

```
function showSections() {
        $('section > h2').each(function() {
            $(this).next('div').show();
            $(this).button({
                icons: {primary: "ui-icon-circle-minus"}
            });
        });
        $('section > h3').each(function() {
            $(this).next('div').show();
            $(this).addClass("d_arrow");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is in `basic.js`.

```
$("#tglTopicBtn").button({
    icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-s"}
}).click(function() {
    lastClickedSection = undefined;
    var options;
    if ($(this).text() === "Expand All Topics") {
        options = {
            label: "Collapse All Topics",
            icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-n"}
        };
        showSections();
    }
    else {
        options = {
            label: "Expand All Topics",
            icons: {primary: "ui-icon-carat-1-s"}
        };
        hideSections();
    }
    $(this).button("option", options);
    updateSelectedSection();
    return false;
});
function hideSections() {
    $('section > h2').each(function() {
        $(this).next('div').hide();
        $(this).button({
            icons: {primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus"}
        });
    });
    $('section > h3').each(function() {
        $(this).next('div').hide();
        $(this).removeClass("d_arrow");
    });
}

function showSections() {
    $('section > h2').each(function() {
        $(this).next('div').show();
        $(this).button({
            icons: {primary: "ui-icon-circle-minus"}
        });
    });
    $('section > h3').each(function() {
        $(this).next('div').show();
        $(this).addClass("d_arrow");
    });
}
```